# How to measure CPU cycles per instruction in a C program

Tags: c, cell, cycle, timing

I have a C program where I am starting to use some SIMD optimizations for the SPE (Cell processor), etc. I would like somehow to "time" how many cycles do they need. One idea is to switch on/off and measure whole execution time. But this is slow. I can also add between and before the execution  gettimeofday(&start,NULL) and so statements, but they are only precise I think when one copes with more than miliseconds.

I wonder if it is possible to measure efficiently the nanoseconds per instruction or just the CPU cycles or some other precise timing measure.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your CPU you may be able to get at [performance registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_performance_counter) within the CPU itself which track instruction clocks and many other useful things. Profilers and other performance utilities can do this, so it should also be possible from user code too. On Mac OS X I would use the Apple CHUD framework, but you didn't state what OS or CPU you are using so it's hard to give specific suggestions.

Comment: I am running a C program under Linux on the Cell processor. There is some system simulator for this, but very complicated to install and understand

Comment: @Werner: Cell does not have SSE2 - that's an x86 SIMD extension - Cell uses its own unique vector instruction set on the SPEs, and AltiVec on the PowerPC-based PPE - which one are you trying to write code for ?

Comment: sorry, yes you are completely right I jsut wrote SSE2 because it is similar and ir onder to make things clear, I will edit this, thanks

Comment: OK - on the Cell SPEs it's a little tricky to calculate cycles. If you read the Cell manual though you'll see that there are odd/even instructions slots and if you schedule your code correctly you may be able to issue one instruction per clock.

Comment: @paul, sorry, i do not see what yoy mean, could you point to a more concrete example?

Comment: @Werner: have you read the Cell manuals at http://ibm.com ? It's all explained in great detail. The SPEs use an odd/even instruction despatch mechanism - some instructions can only be despatched on odd clock cycles and some on even. For maximum throughput you need to schedule your instructions so that you get one issue per clock, i.e. alternating odd/even instructions.

Comment: @Werner: in particular look at Appendix B.1.3.2 ("Issue") of the Cell BE Handbook. It explains the rules for SPE fetch groups and instruction pairs etc. You can get the Cell BE Handbook here: https://www-01.ibm.com/chips/techlib/techlib.nsf/techdocs/1741C509C5F64B3300257460006FD68D/$file/CellBE_PXCell_Handbook_v1.11_12May08_pub.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Execute the code to be tested in a loop and divide the time it takes with the loop counter. The timer you use must not be high resolution to measure correct values.

Comment: Just the loop itself would skew the results extremely.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be When you just want to find out which version of you code is faster, then I think it serves this purpose. Do you agree?

Comment: @frast Yes, but only if the overhead created by the measurement method doesn't skew the results beyond the usable point.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Right. You can not measure a single assembly instruction like xor because the error introduced my the measurement would be much greater than the measured time.

Comment: @frast unless he has access to a system emulator, which I assume only Intel have. If even they have it.

Comment: @frast, unloop the instruction or instructions a number of times before the loop end, could also help a bit.

Comment: this for loop thing is a good idea but in some cases, some set of instructions or single instruction that depends on memry inizialiation, or initial vaules, can get screwd up when doing this. ony simple instructions work with this method

Answer (score 0):

Nano seconds won't be enough for that. You need picoseconds.

I don't think that you can measure something like this reliably. You will have to look into specifications (I'm not sure if current CPUs have this information documented).

Comment: yes, this would be a good idea, I will try to find this information elweshwere,

Answer (score 0):

As a not C guy... my guess is you need to look at the assembly code, and go from there. The only problem is a single instruction could take 1 or 100000 cpu cycles, depending on the exact CPU you are on.

Comment: pity I do not understand assembly. in any case, is it easy to "see" just the translation to assembly of one single C instrunction?